# jQuery Fails To Read JSON Response From PHP Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

In my form, I want to do something with two fields:

"website_domain" and "website_ip_address"

I'm trying to use jQuery/JSON to call a PHP script, pass the website_domain to it, and receive JSON including the IP address of that website.

### Problem/Symptoms Description:

It's partially working: On blur, it GETs the url of the PHP script. I can see that much in firebug. I get a 200 OK. Output from the PHP script is valid JSON according to JSONLint:

{"field":"website_ip_address","value":"74.125.225.70"}

But in Firebug, I don't have a JSON tab. I only have Params and Headers tabs. Not even a Response tab.

Needless to say, the website_ip_address field is also not being populated with the data I should be getting from the PHP script's JSON output.

### My PHP Script:

It may be important to note that for now, this PHP script on a different domain from my application. Maybe my whole problem is cross-domain?

```
<?php 
    $domain = $_GET["domain_name"];
    $ip = gethostbyname($domain);
    // echo $ip;
    $json = array(
        'field' => 'website_ip_address',
        'value' => $ip,
        );
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo json_encode($json );
?>
```

### My jQuery/JSON script:

Note this is written inside a Ruby On Rails application view.

```
:javascript
  $("#website_domain").bind("blur", function(e){
     $.getJSON("http://exampledomain.com/temp_getIP.php?domain_name=" +$("#website_domain").val(),
        function(data){
          $('#website_ip_address').val(data);
        });
});
```

I really hope this isn't just a syntax error on my part. I've been writing/rewriting this for 2 days, based on answers I've found on StackOverflow, to no avail. I'm just missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently attempting to output the JS object (that is formed from the parsed JSON response) to the field. You need to output a value *from within* it. So not:

```
$('#website_ip_address').val(data); //data is an object, not a string
```

but

```
$('#website_ip_address').val(data.someValue); //output a property of the object
```

With your code as it is, I would expect the field to be populated with the string representation of an object, which is `[object Object]`. You don't mention this, so I wonder whether a) your success function is even firing (check this - stick a `console.log` in it); b) your jQ selector is sound.

Comment: Utkanos, you are correct - after Dmitry's cross-domain fix for the PHP script, population is working, and the field is being populated with [object Object] instead of the IP address. I tried changing to your suggested code, and now nothing is populating the field. What am I missing? (i don't know how to 'stick a console.log in it' by the way - too noobish of me!)

Comment: I mean, in your success callback, add a line like `console.log('hello')` then see if that turns up in your console. It's just a means to know whether your callback is firing. If not, there's the problem. If it is, the problem is elsewhere. The simplest form of JS debugging. If it is, it is probably a question of outputting the right value from the response. From the JSON you posted, I would assume this is `data.value`.

Comment: So I should add console.log('It fired!') on another line after $('#website_ip_address').val(data.someValue);, correct?

I tried that, and on blur, I get an "It fired!" showing up in the console.

So, now we conclude the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: Yes - so we know your callback is firing. Next suspect the jQ selector (which sounds like from previous attempts it's working, but let's test anyway). Add the line: `console.log($('#website_ip_address').length)` - if `1` shows up in the console, no problem there.

Comment: OK, now `console.log(data.value)`. Do we see the IP, or `undefined`? If the latter, it's a question of establishing the path to the property (in your object) that you wish to output. Outputting the entire object (`console.log(data)`) can help here.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if this is a shortcut/bad practice, but I tried changing .val(data.someValue); to .val(data.value); and it's working now!!!! So exciting!

Comment: Ahh yes - `someValue` was just my example in my answer! I said in my original comment in reply to your comment, that it should be `data.value`. Probably got missed in the flurry. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: LOL! After I saw you typed "someValue" i looked up data.someValue on google and some discussions seemed to indicate that "some" was important! haha :)

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be with different domain. I had it like this before. Try in php to add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")`

Comment: YES!! Now we're getting somewhere! That was ONE of the problems. Now my script is reading the JSON from the PHP script's output. But, I'm sure Utkanos' answer below will help with, my website_ip_address field is now being populated with: "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

Put your jQuery code inside document ready, example: `$(function(){ });`

```
:javascript
$(function() {
    $("#website_domain").bind("blur", function(e){
        $.getJSON("http://exampledomain.com/temp_getIP.php?domain_name="+$("#website_domain").val(),
           function(data){
               $('#website_ip_address').val(data);
           });
        });
    });
});
```

And you have a missing end `})`

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. It looks like I'm already doing what you suggested in my code. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Also I tried adding }) to the end and got an error. I think I misunderstood that too